# Woocommerce condition to hide fields if cart = $0

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make sure that certain billing information fields are unset if the product is virtual and the cart amounts to $0. I'm having trouble with the second condition. I've tried using conditions from other posts on stackoverflow, but run into a weird issue where all fields are removed if the cart != 0

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'bbloomer_simplify_checkout_virtual' );
 
function bbloomer_simplify_checkout_virtual( $fields ) {
   $only_virtual = true;
   
   global $woocommerce;
    if ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() != 0 ) {
    return;
    }
    
   foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
      // Check if there are non-virtual products
      if ( ! $cart_item['data']->is_virtual() ) $only_virtual = false;   
   }
     
    if( $only_virtual ) {
       unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
       unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
       unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
       unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
       unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
       unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
       unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
       unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);
       add_filter( 'woocommerce_enable_order_notes_field', '__return_false' );
     }
     
     return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() != 0 ) {
    return;
}
```

To

```
if ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() != 0 ) {
    return $fields;
}
```